# OpenSAML Issue - NoClassDefFoundError for TrustMaterial (Java7, Maven)

Tags: java, maven, java-7, noclassdeffounderror, opensaml

We are seeing the following error when trying to complete a single-sign-on using OpenSAML.  This was working, then seemed to stop when we upgraded to Java 7 (though that could very well be a red herring).  We did install the JCE, so don't think it's related to that.  Has anyone encountered this before?

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.commons.ssl.TrustMaterial
    org.opensaml.xml.security.x509.X509Util.decodeCertificate(X509Util.java:319)
    org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.KeyInfoHelper.getCertificate(KeyInfoHelper.java:194)
    org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.KeyInfoHelper.getCertificates(KeyInfoHelper.java:169)
    org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.provider.InlineX509DataProvider.extractCertificates(InlineX509DataProvider.java:191)
    org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.provider.InlineX509DataProvider.process(InlineX509DataProvider.java:125)
    org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver.processKeyInfoChild(BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver.java:299)
    org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver.processKeyInfoChildren(BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver.java:255)
    org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver.processKeyInfo(BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver.java:189)
    org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver.resolveFromSource(BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver.java:148)
    org.opensaml.xml.security.credential.AbstractCriteriaFilteringCredentialResolver.resolve(AbstractCriteriaFilteringCredentialResolver.java:57)
    org.opensaml.xml.security.credential.AbstractCriteriaFilteringCredentialResolver.resolve(AbstractCriteriaFilteringCredentialResolver.java:37)
    org.opensaml.security.MetadataCredentialResolver.retrieveFromMetadata(MetadataCredentialResolver.java:266)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure `not-yet-commons-ssl-0.3.9.jar` is on the classpath of the JVM. That is the jar that contains the `TrustMaterial` class.